# SQL Error 1406 Data too long for column 'concatenado' on local mysql mac osx, it works on Windows perfectly

Tags: mysql, macos

I have a function which allow me to concat each tittle (titulo) of a table size between 50 and 90 words each, until my subtittle (subtitulo) is null initially this has varchar(5000), I discover the return of this function do  not reach aprox 4000 words, this function  is working good in Windows 8 without any problem,I changed to work in MacBook pro osx 10.8.2, I have installed the Mysql latest version as well as I recently changed installing the MAMP , but still with the same problem of the colum , I changed with the type with Text,Long Text,BLOB ,longBlob my IDE shows me the message 'running ...' without stoping, why my function work perfectly in Windows and not in Mac, I have this problem since 4 days ago.

Also my SELECT @@max_allowed_packet shows me on the result 1048576 it that the problem? if so how to add more size in Mac osx.

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost FUNCTION fn_avanceFisico_ConcatenadoTitulos(pIdTitulo int) RETURNS varchar(5000) CHARSET utf8 BEGIN
DECLARE concatenado varchar(5000);

set concatenado='';

WHILE (ifnull(pIdTitulo,0) <> 0) do     
 SELECT concat_ws('</br> Subtitulo',concatenado,titulo),subtitulo into concatenado,pIdTitulo
 FROM ttitulo
 WHERE idTitulo=pIdTitulo;
 END while;

 RETURN concatenado;             

 END;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

the error clearly said it.

you have to make this column `concatenado` longer in database.

if its `varchar(5000)` then increase it till `varchar(6000)` /// this is just example

- Consider using the TEXT types to store long strings.

try that:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost FUNCTION fn_avanceFisico_ConcatenadoTitulos(pIdTitulo int) RETURNS varchar(5000) CHARSET utf8 BEGIN
 DECLARE concatenado varchar(6000);
  .....
  .....
```

Comment: Thanks Echo for your answer, I changed with varchar(6000) as you say and proved with more varchar size, also different types like tex,long tex, etc, when I execute the function show me ¨running ...¨ and does not stop.

Comment: this means your main problem is solved, if doesnt finish you may look to your while loop it still looping without end, i dont know whats going on there.